# Как связывается react и сервер

Tags: reactjs

Только начал изучение react. Возможно я неправильно формулировал вопрос в гугле, но ответа на данном этапе не нашёл. Во всех курсах которые я смотрю, react на порту 3000 взаимодействует с сервером на порту 5000, сервер по итогу выступает в качестве api. Но как сделать так, что бы они работали так сказать на одном порту. Использую сервер написанный на node js, если это важно.

Как я понял, до стадии сборки, сервер всегда выступает в качестве апи, но что происходит после стадии "сборки"?

Comment: Вам может помочь вот этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165056/nginx-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-windows-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2 и еще вот этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163858/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-js-%d0%b2-react-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-rest

Comment: @S.H. спасибо за вторую ссылку, интересно почитать, но в целом вопрос остаётся в силе, попробую конкретизировать его в правке

Comment: ну, у Вас два приложеня, запущенные в разных node.js: рекат-приложение, которое "уедет" на клиента и будет оттуда обращаться к api, и сам server-side. По моему, только через nginx или haproxy их можно заставить оба работать на одном порту... Если есть более простой способ - было бы любопытно узнать!

Comment: Как я понял, после "сборки" react - приложение превращается в набор статических файлов. Если сервер, котрый обслуживает api, может раздавать статику - то проблема решена!

Comment: @S.H. То есть получается react не будет иметь свой сервер, а будет запускаться только сам index html, с реактом, правильно?

Comment: @S.H. понял, спасибо

Comment: Как я понл, реакту сервер нужен для отладки. Типа точки останова поставить и посмотреть, что там в реакте происходит.